# Change YouTube video size with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube

I am trying to make a YouTube video width change when the "onStateChange" event fires on 1(playing) and then make it come back to its original size on 0(ended) and 2(paused).

I am very new to JavaScript and jQuery. But let's say I have this

```
 <section><iframe id="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DjB1OvEYMhY?enablejsapi=1"></iframe></section>
<script>
var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player( 'player', {
          events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange }
        });
      }
</script>
      <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

why does this jquery does not work?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    YT.PlayerState.ENDED = function(e) {
      $('section iframe').animate({ width: "50%"}, 'slow')};

    YT.PlayerState.PAUSED = function(e) {
      $('section iframe').animate({ width: "50%"}, 'slow')};

    YT.PlayerState.PLAYING = function(e) {
    $('section iframe').animate({ width: "100%" }, 'slow');
    }
```

the API information I have got comes from here https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Where is `onYT.PlayerState` defined?

Comment: No errors when I try it on my browser. I got the YT.PlayerState from here
onStateChange

Comment: "This event fires whenever the player's state changes. The data property of the event object that the API passes to your event listener function will specify an integer that corresponds to the new player state. Possible values are:
-1 (unstarted)
0 (ended)
1 (playing)
2 (paused)
3 (buffering)
5 (video cued).
In your code, you can specify the integer values or you can use one of the following namespaced variables:
YT.PlayerState.ENDED

Comment: That's fine, but that's not what you've written in your example. `onYT.PlayerState !== YT.PlayerState`

Comment: I see your point. I deleted the 'on' but it still does not work :/

Comment: ok. why not use `player.PlayerState.ENDED`? as `player` is the youtube player you want to monitor.

Comment: Still a few confusing things here: **1.** Where is `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` called? **2.** Why is the JS in the script tag not inside `.ready` function? **3.** `$('section iframe')` is used, but `section` isn't in the sample HTML.

Comment: **4.** `onPlayerStateChange` is not defined. **5.** `PlayerState.ENDED` and `PlayerState.PLAYING` don't have closing curly braces (`}`).

Comment: Look at the [getting start example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started)

Comment: Do you mean I should call the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady before the jquery? And I don't really understand what you mean when saying to put the javascript inside the .ready function. And yes, I added the <section> part, sorry.

Comment: I mean your approach differs from the getting started youtube api example. E.g. `YT.PlayerState.PAUSED` should not be a function like `element.onclick`. Look how the getting started example works, and use that.